# convert values of a column based on another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, mapping

I have a data.frame

```
df1=data.frame(f=LETTERS[1:4],v=c(1:4))
  f v
1 A 1
2 B 2
3 C 3
4 D 4
```

The first column is a list of factors, in which I have another data frame that houses these values, which  are also factors

```
df2=data.frame(f=LETTERS[1:7],f2=letters[26:20])
  f f2
1 A  z
2 B  y
3 C  x
4 D  w
5 E  v
6 F  u
```

I am wondering how to write a function so that I can alter the values from the first column of df1 to what they map to from df2. I would like to get:

```
  f v
1 z 1
2 y 2
3 x 3
4 w 4
```

I tried a for loop with no success. Ant suggestions is greatly appreciated

Note: this is a simplified example of my work. A merge would add too many columns to work with and I don't think the extra memory storage would be very useful

Comment: @A.Webb if I used a merge, my dfs would have been huge, this is just a simplification of it.

Comment: @alex merge would work just fine

Comment: Any way you frame this question, it's been asked and answered dozens and dozens of times here.

Comment: if I wasn't working for so long, I would have manipulated my dfs so that I could merge... I should have some more coffee I think and finish this off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
 df1$f <- df2$f2[match(df1$f, df2$f)]
 df1
 #  f v
 #1 z 1
 #2 y 2
 #3 x 3
 #4 w 4
```

Comment: that worked magnificently. thanks. I now know about match

Answer (score 1):

You can use `merge`

```
merge(df1,df2,by = "f")[,c(1,3,2)]
  f f2 v
1 A  z 1
2 B  y 2
3 C  x 3
4 D  w 4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df1,df2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the `merge` function to merge the two tables, then specify which columns you want to keep.

For example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(f=LETTERS[1:4],v=c(1:4))
df2 <- data.frame(f=LETTERS[1:7],f2=letters[26:20])

merge(df1, df2, by.x = "f")[,c("f2", "v")]

  f2 v
1  z 1
2  y 2
3  x 3
4  w 4
```